# firebase realtime database rules, give access to user to access another user data

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

i want to give access to users profile to specific users that are set by the users themselves
in this rules i want to let $userid to be able to access $user_id data

(if $user_id exist in allow_list/$userid/), i tried `root.child('allow_list/'+auth.uid+'/$user_id').exists())"` but its not working
this is my rules for now, not working

"users_private":     {

```
     "$user_id":                 {
               ".write": "auth != null && $user_id === auth.uid",
                ".read":"(auth != null) && ($user_id === auth.uid 
            || root.child('allow_list/'+auth.uid+'/$user_id').exists())"
                               } 

              },


  "allow_list":{

                 "$userid": {
```

//ignore these rules they are working

```
  ".read":"auth != null && $userid === auth.uid"  ,

                                 "$user_id": {
         ".write": "($userid == auth.uid || $user_id == auth.uid )&&
                              ( $userid!=$user_id)",


                                               }
                                     }
                  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out how, hope this help someone.

I added `.child`, so the rule will be like this:

```
|| root.child('allow_list/'+auth.uid+'/').child($user_id).exists())
```